# Hie. I want to replace some values from one df to another

Tags: python, excel, pandas, google-sheets, replace

df1

```
Location    Name     Value1    Value2   Value3
Harare      Teddy    345       718      90
Mutare      Freddy   346       800      910
Beitbridge  Kudos    87        567      213
Vic Falls   Tawanda  809       28       56

print(df1.info())
Branch     420
Name       420
Value1     240
Value2     212
Value3     118
```

The difference in the number of entries is a result of not trading. That I am not worried about.

df2

```
Branch       Name
Vic Falls    Tawanda
Mutare       Teddy

print(df2.info())
Branch      240
Name        240
```

I merged these into one df

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='name')
print(df3.info())
Branch    240
Name      240
Value1    234
Value2    168
Value3    112
```

Expected result

```
Location    Name     Value1    Value2   Value3
Mutare      Teddy    345       718      90
Mutare      Freddy   346       800      910
Beitbridge  Kudos    87        567      213
Vic Falls   Tawanda  809       28       56
```

Teddy's location has been updated from its `df1` value to the `df2` value. Every other name, that is not in `df2`, is not edited. If locations are similar in both dfs, then it remains unchanged

Comment: i don't understand what you try to do. Better show in question expected result.

Comment: Hie furas, i have shown the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only idea to use `apply` which gets every row from `df1`, compare `Name` from row with `Name`s in `df2` and if it exists then replace `Location`

```
def func(row):
    row2 = (df2[ df2['Name'] == row['Name'] ])

    if len(row2) == 1:
        row['Location'] = row2['Branch'].iloc[0]

    return row

df1 = df1.apply(func, axis=1)
```

---

Minimal working code.

I use `io.StringIO` only to simulater files in memory.

```
data1 = '''Location    Name     Value1    Value2   Value3
Harare      Teddy    345       718      90
Mutare      Freddy   346       800      910
Beitbridge  Kudos    87        567      213
Vic Falls   Tawanda  809       28       56'''

data2 = '''Branch       Name
Vic Falls    Tawanda
Mutare       Teddy'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data1), sep='\s{2,}')
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data2), sep='\s{2,}')

print(df1)
print(df2)
print('---')

def func(row):
    row2 = (df2[ df2['Name'] == row['Name'] ])

    if len(row2) == 1:
        row['Location'] = row2['Branch'].iloc[0]

    return row

df1 = df1.apply(func, axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Comment: Hie furas. Thank you so much for the solution. I did an extensive test to the code, with multiple dates and checked if the data is giving me the same values(sum), and the results were positive. I have data where users change locations constantly, so calling backdated dfs was giving me errors. So i found on df that had imutable locations which i am now using as the refence point to correct all other data.

Thank you once more.